# Show the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{n}}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know intuitively why this series diverges but I can't really get a proof.

So I am trying to use that the fact that: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{n}} > \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2+{n}} $.

And then from there I want to get it down to something like 1/n, which is a p-series with p=1 therefore it converges, and then use the comparison test to show the original sequence diverges. However I am stuck finding in this middle bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Limit comparison?

Comment: How can you say the last one (with the -3/2) diverges? I understand why it would. But are you able to just say it does without anything further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the answer. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2+n}$ is a tail of the divergent harmonic series and thus diverges itself. The original series therefore diverges by the limit comparison test.

Comment: Could you explain more when you say "tail of the divergent harmonic series"? Thanks.

Comment: @user11015000 A tail of a series is everything but the first $k$ terms, where $k$ is finite. Since the first $k$ terms must sum to a finite number, whether such a tail diverges or not is the same as whether the entire series diverges or not.

Comment: @user11015000 You can see that by tail one means terms as $n \to \infty$. Since as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2+n}$, follows similar behaviour as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}$, the tail diverges.

Comment: How would you show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2+n}$ is a tail of a divergent harmonic series?

Comment: @user11015000  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+n} = \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @user11015000 Suppose this tail converges. Then the entire series converges, for the head must converge, but it doesn't - contradiction.

Comment: Both of these make sense, thank you

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Did you mean that "the original series diverges by the comparison test"? I don't think the limit comparison test can tell us about the relationship between between $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @jawheele Yes. And note that the denominators of the first series are smaller than those of the second series, so the comparison is valid.

Comment: @user11015000 Please ask another question, rather than stuffing questions into one post.